# findViewById() returns null in OnLayoutInflatedListener

Tags: android, wear-os

I've adapted the default code to reference a CircledImageView so that I can set it's background color, but it returns null. I've also tried setting src / background in the xml file for the view, but neither worked. They returned errors, trying to inflate the view.

EDIT: I think the problem might be with `CircledImageView` - has anyone used it successfully?

```
public class MyActivity  extends Activity {

private CircledImageView mCircle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mCircle = (CircledImageView) stub.findViewById(R.id.circle);
            mCircle.setCircleColor(Color.RED);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the watch-view-stub xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/watch_view_stub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:rectLayout="@layout/rect_activity_my"
    app:roundLayout="@layout/round_activity_my"
    tools:context="com.larvalabs.weartest.MyActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">
</android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub>
```

It returns the following error

```
06-27 15:49:14.262    1679-1679/com.larvalabs.weartest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.larvalabs.weartest, PID: 1679
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.larvalabs.weartest.MyActivity$1.onLayoutInflated(MyActivity.java:25)
        at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.inflate(WatchViewStub.java:133)
        at android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub.onMeasure(WatchViewStub.java:141)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2321)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1145)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1340)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1032)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5657)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you show us the XML file for `activity_my`, or at least the portion with `watch_view_stub`?

Comment: CircleImageView is defined as an XML element - you must define it in XML and assign an id to it before you can grab it with findViewById().   You are missing that step. Whatever you do, ensure that you have defined it in your XML before calling findViewById. Removing my answer because it isn't the reason for a null pointer.

Comment: Make sure that you put full class name like android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView in rect_activity_my.xml. Actually I had the same error and in my case I put just <CircledImageView ... ></CircledImageView> in my xml file. After I changed it to <android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView ...></android.support.wearable.view.CircledImageView>, it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do `setContentView` in `onReadyForContent` instead of `onCreate` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that a CircledImageView with id "circle" is in both your round and rect layouts, as specified in your WatchViewStub. In your case, both layout/rect_activity_my.xml and layout/round_activity_my.xml must have a CircledImageView with id="@+id/circle". At runtime, either the rect or round layout will be inflated based on the shape of the screen, so findViewById(R.id.circle) will return null if that layout doesn't have the CircledImageView.